# Making header (ToolBar) fixed in android

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I wrote an android app(Material style).
Here is the code:
**`activity_main.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
        <!--android:layout_toEndOf="@id/fab"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/fab"-->


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**`content_main.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/sample_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <!--My layout-->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/place_holder"
            android:textEditSuggestionItemLayout="@color/colorAccent"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/btn_name"
            android:textEditSuggestionItemLayout="@color/colorAccent"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**`Java code:`**

```
package com.enexl.ajaykulkarni_enexl.omgandroid;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

import static android.widget.Toast.*;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                /*Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();*/
                Context context = getApplicationContext();
                String text = "Let us create an action now!";
                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context,text,duration);
                toast.show();
            }
        });
    }

//    private Toast makeText(Context context, CharSequnce text, int duration) {
//    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Results:
[image: img]
When I click on `editText` field, key board pops up and header(ToolBar in top) goes out of view. Check it in this screen shot:
[image: img2]
I want header(ToolBar in top) to stay in view when keyboard pops up. How can I do it?

Comment: anybody here who can answer my question?

Comment: You can try this in your manifest's activity `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this in my `manifest's activity`:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"
```

And it worked.